# How to configure Docker to communicate over the network?

Tags: docker

I am using the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. How we can make docker deamon on the ubuntu host to listen the network port instead of default local unix port.

I am using following commands.

1. `Service docker stop`
2. `docker -H 10.0.0.50:2375 -d &`

response to the second command (docker -H 10.0.0.50:2375 -d &) was not expected

```
root@chandan-VirtualBox:/home/chandan# docker -H 10.0.0.50:2375 -d &
[1] 4169
root@chandan-VirtualBox:/home/chandan# INFO[0000] +job serveapi(tcp://10.0.0.50:2375)          
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on tcp (10.0.0.50:2375)   
INFO[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANOTHER IP ADDRESS THAN 127.0.0.1 IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
listen tcp 10.0.0.50:2375: bind: cannot assign requested address
INFO[0000] -job serveapi(tcp://10.0.0.50:2375) = ERR (1) 
FATA[0000] listen tcp 10.0.0.50:2375: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

I have checked the port 2375 is unassigned port. But still I am getting a the response right.

Comment: Could you show the output of `ifconfig`? Knowing what interfaces are available might be helpful. Also, try binding to 0.0.0.0:2375 to bind to all interfaces.

Comment: I am using 10.0.0.10/24 ip address, using eth0 for the communication on the network

Answer (score 2):

You will have to enable Docker to listen on remote API port

Try adding below line in the file

```
/etc/default/docker

DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock "
```

Exact steps can be summarised as below

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo vi /etc/default/docker #here you will added the options mentioned above
sudo service docker start
```

check if the port is now listening using this command

```
netstat -plt | grep 2375
```

Happy fixing